The problem with the positioning and dimensions in the apk made through the Kivy framework
Good afternoon! I studied the Kivy framework and compiled several simple apk applications for Android, it seemed that everything was more or less normal. For 3 months I carried out my long-standing idea, wrote a large application for children whom I train (I created a package and inside several dozen scripts.py,images, links, configured import). When debugging in PyCharm, everything looks perfect, for example:
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "360")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "800")

enter image description here
Compiled via buildozer. Debugging was done through Android Studio. Main problems: fonts are much smaller and all positions are incorrect. All positions in FloatLayout are incorrect (relative to what I see in PyCharm). Because of this, I can't draw lines properly in with fl.canvas. Here is an example with an explanation:
enter image description here
It's a shame I spent a lot of time.  Please tell me the possible solutions?
Compiled via buildozer. Debugging was done through Android Studio.
I tried to connect the Python language in Android Studio, but it didn't work out, it would have been easier to debug online.
Now, as an option, binding sizes and positions to Window.width, Window.height, but this will have to be redone and the issue of drawing lines to certain buttons does not solve.
One of the programs:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config


Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "360")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "800")

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition, WipeTransition, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle, BoxShadow
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class StatsApp(App):
    total =0
    def build(self):

        main_layout = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        screen_main_menu = Screen(name="quiz")
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")


        main_menu = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.29)
        w1 = Widget()
        bt_menu = Button(text="--Главное меню--", font_size=27, size_hint_x=3,
                         background_color=[1, 0.55, 0, 1], background_normal="")
        w2 = Widget()
        with w2.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0, .5)
            # Line(points=(0, 0, 443,997), width=10)
            Rectangle(source="bol2.jpg", pos=(358, 907), size=(450 - 359, 1000 - 907))
            Rectangle(source="bol2.jpg", pos=(0, 907), size=(450 - 358, 1000 - 907))
        for w in (w1, bt_menu, w2):
            main_menu.add_widget(w)
            # _____________________________________________

        bl.add_widget(main_menu)


        res = ('никто',"ноль", 'чайник', 'дерево',"ребёнок", 'пацан', 'знаток', 'мастер',
               'звезда', 'гений', 'легенда')

        ind = StatsApp.total

        lb_1 = Label(text=f"Итоговый результат",
                           size_hint_y=0.6, font_size=45,
                           halign="center", valign="center", color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        lb_2 = Label(text=f"{ind*10} %",
                           size_hint_y=0.9, font_size=125,
                           halign="center", valign="center", color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        lb_text = Label(text=f"Ваш уровень в теории футбола:", halign="center", valign="center"
                        , font_size=50, color=[1, 0, 0, 1],size_hint_y=0.3)

        lb_res=Label(text=f"{res[ind]}", halign="center", valign="center"
                        , font_size=80, color=[1, 0, 0, 1])

        lb_text.text_size = 380, 550
        lb_1.text_size = 380, 550

        for lb in lb_1,lb_2,lb_text,lb_res:
            bl.add_widget(lb)

        def go_main_menu(instance: Button):
            from nosta_2014 import main as ml
            from nosta_2014 import quiz
            screen2 = Screen(name="main_menu")
            tl = ml.Nosta2014App.build("")
            screen2.add_widget(tl)
            main_layout.add_widget(screen2)
            main_layout.current = "main_menu"
            quiz.QuizApp.total = 0

        bt_menu.bind(on_press=go_main_menu)

        screen_main_menu.add_widget(bl)
        main_layout.add_widget(screen_main_menu)


        with bl.canvas.before:
            Color(1, 1, 0, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(447, 1000))




        return main_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    StatsApp().run()


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not sure if this is the problem, but I see that you set the size of your App to 360x800 with your Config.set statements. Then your graphics commands are using 'x' and 'y' coordinates that are outside that size.
